# Sharing data between hierarchy of objects using StructureMap

Tags: structuremap

My question is related to StructureMap and how to instantiate the object to share data between the hierarchy of objects within same http request context?

I have the below hierarchy of classes which generates some data.

```
IPageBuilder
    -> IShipmentBuilder
        -> IItemBuilder
            -> IItemShippingOptionBuilder
        -> IShippingOptionBuilder
        -> IDeliveryMethodBuilder
    -> IPaymentBuilder
    -> ISummaryBuilder
```

In the client code: we use IPageBuilder.Build() will call the hierarchy of builders and returns an object.

Basically, We want to share some data from IItemBuilder to ISummaryBuilder. Eg., IItemBuilder makes an API call and the response should be shared also with ISummaryBuilder.

Tried Approach: Introduce an object such as IDataContext and pass it as argument in all above builders, but this seems to be tedious solution.

Expected Solution: Is there a way using StructureMap where I can inject IDataContext in IItemBuilder, store some data and the same data should be shared with ISummaryBuilder and it should happen for each http request context.

In short, is there a way to create a singleton per http request In structuremap?

Comment: How to use containers in structuremap to create object per http request? I want to create an object something like tempdata object which should live only on that http request context lift?

Answer (score 0):

Imported Package StructureMap.Web and Used HttpContextBasedLifeCycle for IDataContext and preserved a dictionary within DataContext concrete class to persist the data until the lifetime of httpContext.